# some of my outputs have both the if condtional output and else conditional output, how should i modify so the output is correct? Thank you

Tags: python

Write a program that takes a date as input and outputs the date's season in the northern hemisphere. The input is a string to represent the month and an int to represent the day.

Ex: If the input is:

April
11
the output is:

Spring
In addition, check if the string and int are valid (an actual month and day).

Ex: If the input is:

Blue
65
the output is:

Invalid
The dates for each season in the northern hemisphere are:
Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month == ('April' or 'May') and 1<= input_day <=31:
    print('Spring')
if input_month == ('March') and 20<= input_day <= 31:
    print('Spring')
if input_month == ('June') and 1<= input_day <= 20:
    print('Spring')

if input_month == ('July' or 'August') and 1<= input_day <=31:
    print('Summer')
if input_month == ('June') and 20<= input_day <= 30:
    print('Summer')
if input_month == ('September') and 1<= input_day <= 21:
    print('Summer')

if input_month == ('October') and 1<= input_day <= 31:
    print('Autumn')
if input_month == ('November') and 1<= input_day <=31:
    print('Autumn')
if input_month == ('September') and 22<= input_day <= 30:
    print('Autumn')
if input_month == ('December') and 1<= input_day <= 20:
    print('Autumn')

if input_month == ('January') and 1<= input_day <= 31:
    print('Winter')
if input_month == ('February') and 1<= input_day <= 28:
    print('Winter')
if input_month == ('December') and 21<= input_day <= 31:
    print('Winter')
if input_month == ('March') and 1 <=input_day <= 19:
    print('Winter')

else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Below is the test results I got for the code

```
Total score: 6 / 10

1:Compare output
0 / 1
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Input
April
11
Your output
Spring
Invalid
Expected output
Spring
2:Compare output
1 / 1
Input
March
3
Your output
Winter
3:Compare output
1 / 1
Input
Word
21
Your output
Invalid
4:Compare output
1 / 1
Input
February
39
Your output
Invalid
5:Compare output
0 / 1
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Input
June
21
Your output
Summer
Invalid
Expected output
Summer
6:Compare output
0 / 1
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Input
November
7
Your output
Autumn
Invalid
Expected output
Autumn
7:Compare output
1 / 1
Input
September
31
Your output
Invalid
8:Compare output
1 / 1
Input
December
-1
Your output
Invalid
9:Compare output
1 / 1
Input
February
0
Your output
Invalid
10:Compare output
0 / 1
Output differs. See highlights below. 
Special character legend
Input
October
31
Your output
Autumn
Invalid
Expected output
Autumn
```

Comment: A lot of conditions can be simplified. Why are you checking multiple times if day is between 1 and 31? do it once at the beginning. Then for months belonging to more than one season (eg: march), put two conditions inside that month to check if day is above or below the threshold day. Having said that, you are allowing invalid days, like 31 for months with 30 days and 29,30 and 31 for february

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate all your complex checks, I used the dictionary data structure and a couple of lists.  I also created a namedtuple called Season which defines a tuple consisting of the season as a string followed by two ints indicating the first day of the month the season is valid as well as the last day of the month the season is valid.    Thus, some months have two Season records for the respective seasons.  Here is my code:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Season = namedtuple('Season',['SN', 'stDay', 'ndDay'])
def findSeason():
    months = ['January', 'Febuary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
             'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    month_length = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
    calendar = {'January':[Season('Winter', 1, 31)],
               'February': [Season('Winter', 1, 29)],
               'March': [Season('Winter', 1, 19), Season('Spring', 20, 31)],
               'April': [Season('Spring', 1, 30)],
               'May': [Season('Spring', 1, 31)],
               'June': [Season('Spring', 1, 20), Season('Summer', 21, 30)],
               'July': [Season('Summer', 1, 31)],
               'August': [Season('Summer', 1, 31)],
               'September': [Season('Summer', 1, 21), Season('Autumn', 22, 30)],
               'October': [Season('Autumn', 1, 31)],
               'November': [Season("Autumn", 1, 30)],
               'December': [Season('Autumn', 1, 20), Season('Winter', 21, 31)]}
    day = None
    month = None
    mnth_indx = None
    while True:
        month = input("Please enter a month: ")
        if month in calendar.keys():
            mnth_indx = months.index(month)
            break
        print(f"Please enter a valid Month to include: {', '.join(months)}")
    while True:
        day = int(input("Please enter a day: "))        
        if day > 0 and day <= month_length[mnth_indx]:
            break
        print(f"Please enter a valid day in range of 1 to {month_length[mnth_indx]} for the month of {month}") 
    season_list = calendar[month]
    for sn in season_list:
        if day >= sn.stDay and day <= sn.ndDay:
            print (f'The Current Season is {sn.SN}')
            return
    print('Error Invalid Data')
    return
```

To run execute:
`findSeason()`
This will result in something along the lines of:

```
Please enter a month: Septembeer
Please enter a valid Month to include: January, Febuary, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December
Please enter a month: September
Please enter a day: 16
The Current Season is Summer
```

​

Comment: Thanks for the anwer. I'm no longer as idiotic and lazy as I was a few months back :[}

Comment: It wasnt the answer but, the techniques that you used in your code taught me alot.

Comment: If not the appropriate answer please add your own answer to the question, so we may all learn.  Once you have added the answer you can accept it, so we all know there is an answer.